# Add version from property file to maven log

Tags: java, maven-2

I have project, which contains some modules. Each module contain .properties file, which in addition to project version contains time stamp. I've found a lot of questions about how to replace version in pom file to version from property file, but my question is, can I make maven additionally output string with version from property file? I mean, i want build output start with short version which is in the pom file

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Some-project 1.0.0.0-version
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] And here should be something like FULLL VERSION IS : 1.0.0.0-additional-info
```

Is it possible?

I'm using maven-2

Comment: I don't know of any plugin that does this, but writing one that just prints a string might take a few minutes and you can configure to print something like `FULL VERSION ${project.version}`

Comment: My question is: Why do you have property file which contains the version whereas the pom.xml is the right place to put the information about versions? And why the timestamp? Every heard about SNAPSHOT's ?